# odata Execute crm action

Tags: c#, odata, dynamics-crm

I have action that I try to run. This is the action definition:

```
 <ComplexType Name="vip_MemberProgramResponse">
    <Property Name="MembershipId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" Unicode="false" />
    <Property Name="ResponseCode" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" Unicode="false" />
    <Property Name="ResponseMessage" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" Unicode="false" />
  </ComplexType>
  <Action Name="vip_MemberProgram">
    <Parameter Name="memberProgramInput" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" Unicode="false" />
    <ReturnType Type="mscrm.vip_MemberProgramResponse" Nullable="false" />
  </Action>
```

this is my action call:

```
await client.ExecuteActionAsScalarAsync<string>
 ("vip_MemberProgram", new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
       { "memberProgramInput" , "this is parameter value"}

    });
```

When I execute it I am getting exception:

> A null value was found for the property named 'MembershipId', which has the expected type 'Edm.String[Nullable=False]'. The expected type 'Edm.String[Nullable=False]' does not allow null values.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: In your action you have set `MembershipId` to null.

Comment: But MembershipId , ResponseCode,ResponseMessage are output values

Comment: Correct, and you never set its value

Comment: Ok. Thanks. So this is server error?

Comment: I would say it is a validation of server result

Comment: You also have to set ResonseCode and ResponseMessage to some value, as they are marked as not nullable as well as MembershipId